# Can we alter the UID of NFC Type 2 tags using Android programming?

Tags: android, tags, nfc, uniqueidentifier, rfid

I have to find out NFC tag ID and alter that ID. I already found out the ID using the method `tag.getId()`. Now I want to alter that ID.

```
mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
byte[] id = mTag.getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, on typical Type 2 tags the UID (anti-collision identifier) is factory programmed, read only, and cannot be changed. There exist, however, some NFC-A tags with changabe UID. Moreover, there are emulator devices that can emulate aritrary UID values.